# How to share files between application running on multiple servers

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I have a java application running on Apache tomcat on two different servers A and B. The application involves uploading and downloading files mostly pdf and images. Currently I have an FTP server F ,where I host all my files. Now I am having the following problems:

1. Uploading and Downloading of files is causing issues while creating FTP connection (Sometimes it connects and Sometimes it throws the timeout error).
2. I am displaying images by converting them into BASE 64 format, which causes the same trouble discussed above.

Solutions that I can think of is

1. Use application server to host files (Is it a right practice??),
   also as I have two different servers running the application it
   would be tough to create a sync between them.
2. I have heard something about shared file hosting but that will cause security troubles.

Any solutions for my above problem would be really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses a database, you could store these files as LOBs (Character or binary large objects)in the database instead of on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are small you can store them as CLOB or BLOB in a database and serve them through HTTP (rest endpoints from your application server)

If your files are large, store them in a NAS or any other shared storage. Don't convert them to BASE64 instead serve them as binary attachments over HTTP (rest endpoints from your application server). You may or may not store the file locations somewhere maybe in Database to keep track of it.